# Any idea what this is?

Tags: subaru, part-identification, legacy

I found this in my driveway under my car (2013 Subaru Legacy), so I can only assume it broke off.  Any idea what it is??

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has broken off one of the suspension coil springs.

You need to get this fixed soon.  The coil spring will not be seated properly anymore and the sharp end of the remaining coil spring could move and puncture the tyre, since they are usually located very close to the tyres.

[image]

This is just an example of a coil spring I got from [here](https://www.buycarparts.co.uk/suplex/8313323).  The piece you have found is from one of the ends of the spring.

Comment: Makes more sense with the pic. Nice job. +1

Comment: It looks like a significant steel making /wire drawing defect on the fractured end ( the angled end with the mostly silky gray surface.)  But nut a good view for analysis.

Comment: I agree with @HandyHowie that it is a broken coil spring I would also that the most common cause of spring failure is worn struts. It may be worth installing a pair of what is referred to as a loaded strut . That is  a new strut with a spring mounted on it and in some cases the strut mount is also included.

Comment: SteveH - If this is indeed a piece of the spring off of your Legacy, I'd be looking at the front end. Reason being, the rear springs on your car are much tighter than the front ones. Check to see if either side is a bit lower than the other on level ground. @mikes has a good idea about replacement struts/springs.